# How to fix data duplication/deletion when clicking back/forward buttons in react router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm building an moving web application with the following relationships: a USER has many MOVES --> a MOVE has many BOXES --> a BOX has many ITEMS.

I have the functionality working so that when you click on a specific MOVE, you are routed to a list of all the BOXES associated with that MOVE.

However, if I am on the list of BOXES page and click back to the list of MOVES page, my MOVES duplicate. And similarly, when I click back into a specific MOVE, my BOXES duplicate. And at some points, if I do a total page refresh, my data either 1. Completely disappears (i.e., componentDidMount() is perhaps not working on page refresh?) OR 2. my app breaks and receive this error: "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance".

My goal is just to have the back and forward functionality working properly so that my data is mounted once and just stays the same.

I have tried fixing the issue within my componentDidMount() method inside of both my MoveList and BoxList component. I looked into some posts about browser history and tried the following in order to limit my componentDidMount() to ONE TIME.
    
    `componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.history.action === "POP") {
      this.props.getMoves(this.props.user.user_id)
    }
  }`

```
MoveList.js

import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getMoves } from '../actions/moveActions'
import Move from './Move'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class MoveList extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.history.action === "POP") {
      this.props.getMoves(this.props.user.user_id)
    }
  }

  render() {

    const mappedMoves = this.props.moves.map((move) => {

  return <Move move={move} key={move.id} />
})

return (
  <div className="row">
      {mappedMoves}
  </div>
)
  }
        }  


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

  return {
    moves: state.moves,
    user: state.user
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getMoves: () => dispatch(getMoves())
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MoveList));



BoxList.js (u click a Move to see this box list)

import React from 'react';
import Box from './Box';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getBoxes } from '../actions/boxActions'

class BoxList extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.history.action === "PUSH") {
      this.props.getBoxes(this.props.user.user_id, this.props.move.id)
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log("boxlist props", this.props.history);

    const mappedBoxes = this.props.boxes.map((box, idx) => {
      return <Box box={box} key={box.id} idx={idx}/>
    })

    return (
      <div className="col s9">
          {mappedBoxes}
      </div>
     )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    move: state.move,
    boxes: state.boxes,
    user: state.user
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getBoxes: (userId, moveId) => dispatch(getBoxes(userId, moveId))
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BoxList))
```

The expected result happens on the first load. However, if I click back and forth the data either dupes or disappears.
Here's my router:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/moves" component={MoveContainer} />
            <Route path="/boxes" render={(props) => <BoxContainer {...props} />} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs, because every time you go back to the page, the component is reassembled, and the getMoves action is triggered, thus adding the data to the array, even the ones already in it. To resolve this, you can add elements to your array as follows:

```
    function uniqueData(value, index, self) {
         return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }

    moves = moves.concat(data).filter(uniqueData);
```

As we can see above, the array moves is concatenated with the array data, which in this case would refer to the data that will be added in the array moves, and soon after being concatenated, it is filtered, using the uniqueData function, thus removing all duplicate data from the array moves.

Comment: Thank you, i actually was able to figure out another way, via dynamic route parameters. i was using my redux store to store my params but it clears on refresh.